# pdo mysql join not working

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

I am trying to show the list of friends in each profile, but at the moment im getting no errors but its not showing any friends

my tables are as followed:

users 
    - id
    - username
    - email

friends
    - id
    - user1
    - user2

and here is my function from the class

```
public function getfriends($m)
    {
        $user_id = $m; // User table user_id value

        $query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT a.username FROM users a, friends b WHERE a.id = b.user1 AND b.user2 = ?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $user_id);

        $query->execute();

        $fetch = $query->fetchAll();

        foreach($fetch as $row)
        {
            $username = $row['username'];

            $each .= 'friend '.$username.' ';
        }

        return $each;

    }
```

then im echo the results

```
<?php echo $user->getfriends($id); ?>
```

Comment: And if you try to run this query with a legit value for `b.user2` in your phpmyadmin - does it return results?

Comment: i have added the friend in the phpmyadmin, its just not showing with this code

Comment: How can you be sure that this query should return any results?
You should try to run this query in your phpmyadmin first in order to know if the problem is with the query or not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try specifying data type for parameter sent?

```
$query->bindValue(1, $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```